# how to get a record based on max date for each user in different multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make a query that can select the names, DateOfSpecimenResult,SwabResult,DateOfReleaseOfResult. Heres the Visual Representation:

**Table: ContactTracingHeader**

```
| AutoID |   Name  | 
    1       Jason
    2       Chris
```

**Table: Swab**

```
| PatientNo | DateOfSpecimenCollection | SwabResultID | DateOfReleaseOfResult |
      1             05/02/2020                1               05/10/2020
      1             06/08/2020                1               06/11/2020
      1             07/16/2020                2               07/20/2020
```

*Note: ContactTracingHeader.AutoID = Swab.PatientNo*

**Table: SwabResult**

```
| AutoID | SwabResult |
     1      POSITIVE
     2      NEGATIVE
```

**Query Output that I'm trying to make**

```
| AutoID |  Name  | DateOfSpecimenCollection | SwabResult | DateOfReleaseOfResult |
     1     Jason          07/16/2020            NEGATIVE          07/20/2020
     2     Chris          (BLANK)               (BLANK)            (BLANK)
```

*Note: Swab.ResultID = SwabResult.AutoID*

Here, I'm only trying to show a `Name` with the latest `DateOfSpecimenCollection` and then use it as a reference for the 2 other column which is `SwabResult` and `DateOfReleaseOfResult`, And Since "Chris" doesn't have a input on the *Swab* table, his records are blank but his name and `AutoID` Still appears on the table. The `SwabResult` shows the `NEGATIVE`, or `POSITIVE` depending on the ID from table *Swab*.

What i have done so far is this:

```
SELECT
CTH.AutoID, 
CTH.Firstname, 
CTH.Lastname, 

(SELECT MAX(DateOfSpecimenCollection)
            FROM Swab
            WHERE Swab.PatientNo = CTH.AutoID
        ) AS DateOfSpecimenCollection,

Swab.SwabResultID,

Swab.DateOfReleaseOfResult

FROM ContactTracingHeader AS CTH LEFT JOIN Swab ON Swab.PatientNo = CTH.AutoID;
```

This Query gets the latest `DateOfSpecimenCollection` and Output those who aren't in the *Swab* table which is correct, however it duplicates the record depending how many `SwabResult` or `DateOfReleaseOfResult` it has. Also I tried `INNER JOIN` the table *SwabResult* so i can output the `SwabResult` instead of the ID, However it gave me JOIN Expression not supported Error.

I apologize for the long and confusing explanation and duplicate question as I'm trying to strugge to find some answers on the internet. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need a unique identifier in Swab table. If not already there, autonumber should serve

Consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT Swab.* FROM Swab WHERE ID IN 
   (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Swab AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.PatientNo=Swab.PatientNo 
    ORDER BY Dupe.DateOfSpecimenCollection DESC);
```

Query2

```
SELECT ContactTracingHeader.AutoID, ContactTracingHeader.Name, Query1.DateOfSpecimenCollection, 
SwabResult.SwabResult, Query1.DateOfReleaseOfResult
FROM ContactTracingHeader LEFT JOIN (SwabResult RIGHT JOIN Query1 
ON SwabResult.AutoID = Query1.SwabResultID) 
ON ContactTracingHeader.AutoID = Query1.PatientNo;
```

Or this sequence:

Query1:

```
SELECT Swab.PatientNo, Max(Swab.DateOfSpecimenCollection) AS MaxOfDateOfSpecimenCollection
FROM Swab
GROUP BY Swab.PatientNo;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Swab.PatientNo, Swab.DateOfSpecimenCollection, Swab.SwabResultID, 
Swab.DateOfReleaseOfResult
FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Swab 
ON (Query1.MaxOfDateOfSpecimenCollection = Swab.DateOfSpecimenCollection) 
AND (Query1.PatientNo = Swab.PatientNo);
```

Query3:

```
SELECT ContactTracingHeader.AutoID, ContactTracingHeader.Name, 
Query2.DateOfSpecimenCollection, SwabResult.SwabResult, Query2.DateOfReleaseOfResult
FROM SwabResult RIGHT JOIN (ContactTracingHeader LEFT JOIN Query2 
ON ContactTracingHeader.AutoID = Query2.PatientNo) 
ON SwabResult.AutoID = Query2.SwabResultID;
```

Comment: I knew it that you need two queries for this, i keep forcing myself to use a single query. I thought i was getting some errors when i see those parameter values. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is possible to nest the first query inside the second for an all-in-one statement.